# deploy .rdl with tfs 2015 build definition

Tags: tfsbuild, ssrs-2012, tfs-2015

I have several .rdl files I want to integrate to my TFS 2015 update 3 with continuos integration.

I have the Data Tools installed on the Build Server, therefore I can compile the Visual Studio project with the report files (rdl).

How can i deploy them using a build definition like a .net web app??

I have read several methods like using rs.exe, powershell, etc. No one seems to be a clear way to integrate TFS 2015 with Reporting Services

Comment: Did you mean you want to publish those .rdl files to a report server?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, I want to publish them using TFS 2015 build definition. I know how to publish them with command line, visual studio or manually. Now I want to integrate it with a Continuos Integration Solution like TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Command line task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/command-line) in TFS Build definition, and specify the tool you want to run in this task:

[image]

Also, select the CI trigger in the definition:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however my request is more specific to reporting services. If there is an standard way to deploy / publish in the new TFS 2015 build system.

Comment: There is no such default tasks or extensions currently. So use Command Line task to specify the tool (rs.exe, powershell, etc) you want to run is the only option.